# how to select a row of another table in the same transaction

Tags: mysql, select, transactions

I have two tables called `table1` and `table2`.
`table1` has fields `code varchar`, `state int`.
`table2` has fields `code varchar`, `name varchar`.

I have this transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (CODE,STATE)VALUES ('001',1);
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (CODE,STATE)VALUES ('001','X VALUE');
COMMIT;
```

`table2` has the trigger `trigger1`

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE2
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE STATE INT;
        SET STATE=(SELECT STATE FROM TABLE1 WHERE CODE=NEW.CODE); -- MY QUESTION.

        IF (STATE=0 )THEN
            DO SMETHING....
        END IF;

END |
```

Question:  How I can get in the trigger the value of the field `state` of the the row inserted in the same transaction.

Comment: Is your shift key stuck?

Comment: I unstuck it for him.